# Meteor Flow Router issue with update

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app and I'm transitioning from IronRouter to FlowRouter. So far so good, but there are aspects I don't understand yet.

I have a route as follows:

```
FlowRouter.route('/documents/:docId/edit', {
  name: 'documentEdit',
  subscriptions: function (params, queryParams) {
    this.register('documentEdit', Meteor.subscribe('documentSingle', params.docId));
  },
  action: function (params, queryParams) {
    BlazeLayout.render('layout', { top: 'header', main: 'documentEdit' });
  },    
});
```

**First option:**

Then I also have a template:

```
<template name="documentEdit">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit document</h1>
    {{#if isReady 'documentEdit'}}
      {{#autoForm collection="Documents" doc=this id="documentForm" type="update" meteormethod="documentUpdateMethod"}}
        <fieldset>
          {{> afQuickField name='title'}}
          {{> afQuickField name='content' rows=6}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        <a class="btn btn-link" role="button" href="{{pathFor 'documentsList'}}">Back</a>
      {{/autoForm}}
      {{/if}}
   </div>
</template>
```

with a template helper as follows:

```
Template.documentEdit.helpers({
 isReady: function(sub) {
    if(sub) {
      return FlowRouter.subsReady(sub);
    } else {
      return FlowRouter.subsReady();
    }
  }
});
```

This is as it is mentioned [here](https://meteorhacks.com/flow-router-and-subscription-management#subscription-management), but I'm not getting the values pre-filled in the textboxes on the UI (which is normal when editing fields).

**Second option:**

When I do the following it works and I don't really understand why it works (found it browsing in different forums and tried it out):

```
<template name="documentEdit">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit document</h1>
    {{#with getDocument }}
      {{#autoForm collection="Documents" doc=this id="documentForm" type="update" meteormethod="documentUpdateMethod"}}
        <fieldset>
          {{> afQuickField name='title'}}
          {{> afQuickField name='content' rows=6}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        <a class="btn btn-link" role="button" href="{{pathFor 'documentsList'}}">Back</a>
      {{/autoForm}}
    {{/with}}
   </div>
</template>
```

and the helper:

```
Template.documentEdit.helpers({
 getDocument: function () {
    return Documents.findOne();
 }
});
```

So the questions are:

- for the 1st option: any idea why it does not work. I would prefer that one as it's the documented way of doing things
- for the 2nd option: not sure why I need (in the template helper) to do a `Document.findOne()` without even having to pass the id of the doc I want to edit:

Comment: Looking at the first option, I am wondering what `doc=this` is supposed to do. I am quite sure it does not point to anything relevant unless you specify it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I removed it, but doesn't improve things.

Comment: Well, you probably need to assing `this` to something relevat, i.e. the result of your `getDocument` helper.

Comment: The reason you're probably experiencing the problem after switching from `iron` to `flow` router is that `iron` was implicitly assigning value to the `this` data context and that was done by `data` hook. In `flow-router` there are no `data` hooks so you need to set your context explicitly, like you did in the "second option". Alternatively, you can write `doc=getDocument` as I suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: It works indeed. But my main problem is that I don't understand that the getDocument is 'just' doing a Document.FindOne(). Which one? I'm not passing in a parameter id to find that single document I want to edit. So how can it work? In IronRouter, to achieve this I was using the data portion of the route to fetch the data, but I was always providing (in case of an edit) the 'this.params._id' so it was clear 'which' data I wanted to pass to the template view. In Flow Router, I'm doing a Document.FindOne() without specifying which one (not passing an _id)...and seems to template knows which one.

Comment: Apparently, your subscription is designed to only fetch once document from the server and I assume it's done by providing document id. When you call `findOne` on the client side it only searches the local copy of your database, so in this particular case there's only one document and it's the right one.

Comment: OK, appreciate your help. I understand your last comment, but feels a bit odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do template level subscriptions with Flow Router, that's one of the primary pattern changes.

So you'd do:

Setup the subscription at the template level. Autorun so it'll resubscribe on route changes.

```js
Template.documentEdit.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;
  this.autorun(function() {
    var docId = FlowRouter.getParam('docId');
    self.subscribe('documentSingle', docId));
  };
};
```

Setup the template helper to pick up from the route, and grab the id and populate the helper/document.

```js
Template.documentEdit.helpers({
  getDocument: function () {
    var docId = FlowRouter.getParam('docId');
    var doc = Documents.findOne(docId) || {};
    return doc;
  }
});
```

Do a template level load check and if it's there render it, otherwise show loading...

```js
<template name="documentEdit">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit document</h1>
    {{#if Template.subscriptionReady}}
      {{#with getDocument }}
        {{#autoForm collection="Documents" doc=this id="documentForm" type="update" meteormethod="documentUpdateMethod"}}
        <fieldset>
          {{> afQuickField name='title'}}
          {{> afQuickField name='content' rows=6}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        <a class="btn btn-link" role="button" href="{{pathFor 'documentsList'}}">Back</a>
        {{/autoForm}}
      {{/with}}
    {{else}}
      Loading...
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It's Template.subscriptionsReady with 's'

Comment: Good catch Joe. That indeed made it work. Also thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how this worked, seeing that all the tutorials I have read that deals with update used Iron router, I have spent 7 days worth of trying retrying, looking through others code, reading tutorials. Happy it now works.